# How to select all elements in class, including dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements with the class "qss". I would like to go through them via a loop and change their text as per an array. It's all working fine, except if there are some qss elements that were added dynamically by JQuery (via .clone), those qss elements aren't picked up by this function. How can I go through all qss elements regardless of whether they are dynamically added?

This is my current code:

```
i = 0
$('body').find('.qss').each(function(){
  $(this).text(big_array[i]);
  i++;
});
```

Comment: Once an element is in the DOM, it doesn't matter how it was created. Dynamic elements should be found.

Comment: Are you sure this code is running after they were added?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities, either with a simple `for` loop with a better performance, or with the `each()` function and using the [index parameter](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```js
var beforeArray = ['before 01', 'before 02', 'before 03'],
  bigArray = ['after 01', 'after 02', 'after 03'];

// create dynamic elements
var beforeArrayLength = beforeArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < beforeArrayLength; i++) {
  $('body').append(
    $('<p></p>').addClass('qss').text(beforeArray[i])
  );
}

setTimeout(function() {
  // first possibility with better performance
  // but you have to put it in a function where $qss is always newly set
  var $qss = $('body').find('.qss'),
    qssLength = $qss.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < qssLength; i++) {
    $qss[i].innerHTML = bigArray[i];
  }

  // second possibility
  $('body').find('.qss').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).text(bigArray[index]);
  });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try using each() like this

```
$('.qss').each(function(i, obj) {
    //you can use this to access the current item
});
```

where 'i' is the postion in the array and obj is the DOM object that you are iterating (can be accessed through the jQuery wrapper $(this) as well).

Comment: While I agree that this is a better way to write it, why wouldn't it work the way he wrote it?